# search first x characters from excel range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to search an Excel range for specific text, and return how many are found, but want to search only on the first 4 characters. I have

```
=SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(FIND("V",E4:E40)))
```

which does search the range, but it finds all `V`'s and not those just in the first 4 characters. The data starts with a 4 character acronym and then has free form text.

I'm unable to get `LEFT` to work in this formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(-- (LEFT(E4:E40,4) = "VOID"))
```

If you only want to see if `V` is in the first 4 letters:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(FIND("V",E4:E40 & "XXXXV")<=4))
```

concatenating the `& "XXXXV"` on the end removes the possiblity of the error.  So the Find will return a number.  We then test whether that `V` is found in the first 4 characters.

We added four`X` to the string to ensure that if the value has a length less than 4 we do not get false positives.

Comment: It's so easy when you see it done. Thanks that is working like a charm.